# Call C program from PHP

Tags: php

How can I call a C program from PHP? I have tried with system exec or shell _exec. This is a C program I've written.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `exec` or similar function.

Comment: i have doing but not working !!!, i have seen log file from server, i have found like this 
[78185.893420] watchbox_nagios[27662]: segfault at 0 ip b7b69511 sp bfe011fc error 4 in libc-2.9.so[b7b09000+15c000]

Comment: i have changed with sudo chmod 777 programmname, but not working!!1

Comment: @farka: chmod will not fix anything. your program and/or system are broken, hence the segfault.